# Did the Risen Lord appear to Mother Mary?

Tags: catholicism, virgin-mary, gospels, resurrection

We see the Gospels narrating how Mother Mary was present at the crucifixion of Jesus (John 19:25–27). But we do not see an explicit narration, or even a mention, of Jesus appearing to His mother after His resurrection. My question is: how does the Catholic Church explain the absence of such a narration  in the Gospels?

Comment: My question's focus  is NOT on whether Jesus appeared to Mary post -resurrection or not, BUT on why there is no mention in the Gospels on such apparition.